# app running on simulator but not in ipad..!

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, colors, ipad, ios-simulator

A'm stucked with a very strange problem.....really cant get how to come out with that..!!

I am developing iPad application in which I am drawing a 3d cube with openGL programming for ipad....Everything is fine....I drawn the cube and also colored it with different colors....This all things I have tested on simulator, everything is great. But when I tried to test on iPad, my cube is being drawn but coloring part is not working...!!!

Thanks in advance for help..!!

Comment: OpenGL has some slight differences between the simulator and devices. Post your drawing code.

Comment: Does this drawProperties make any difference ??


eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

Comment: Hey, I found one problem..actually for coloring I was using plist file. Like, when user select in any color at that time I was storing that color value in plist and then in my renderer class I was taking that value of color from plist. So when I was working on simulator everything was fine, but when I debug the same thing on device I could not get the value of color from plist in my renderer class..!! Does plist have some restrictions to use in actual device?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** : My sample code

MyViewController.h

```
    CubeView *cubeView;
```

---

MyViewController.m

```
    cubeView = [[CubeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 60, 450, 600)];
    cubeView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    cubeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self.view addSubview:cubeView];
```

---

CubeView.m

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{    
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder]))
    {

        // Get the layer
        CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

        eaglLayer.opaque = TRUE;
        eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
//      self.frame = CGRectMake(20, 30, 500, 500);
        renderer = nil;
        if (!renderer)
        {
            renderer = [[CubeRenderer alloc] init];

            if (!renderer)
            {
                [self release];
                return nil;
            }
        }

    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Get the layer
        CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

        eaglLayer.opaque = TRUE;
        eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
        renderer = nil;
        if (!renderer)
        {
            renderer = [[CubeRenderer alloc] init];

            if (!renderer)
            {
                [self release];
                return nil;
            }
        }

    }   
    return self;
}
```

---

CubeRenderer.m

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

        if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context])
        {
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }

        currentCalculatedMatrix = CATransform3DIdentity;

        // Create default framebuffer object. The backing will be allocated for the current layer in -resizeFromLayer
        glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &defaultFramebuffer);
        glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
        glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, defaultFramebuffer);
        glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
        glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);

    }

    return self;
}

    static const GLfloat cubeVertices[] = {

        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,

        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    };

    static const GLushort cubeIndicesFaceFront[] = {
        0, 1, 2, 3, 0
    };

    static const GLushort cubeIndicesFaceBack[] = {
        4, 5, 6, 7, 4
    };

    static const GLushort cubeIndicesFaceLeft[] = {
        0, 4, 7, 3, 0
    };

    static const GLushort cubeIndicesFaceRight[] = {
        1, 5, 6, 2, 1
    };

    static const GLushort cubeIndicesFaceTop[] = {
        3, 2, 6, 7, 3
    };

    static const GLushort cubeIndicesFaceBottom[] = {
        0, 1, 5, 4, 0
    };


    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];


    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
        glOrthof(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0 * 480.0 / 320.0, 2.0 * 480.0 / 320.0, -3.0, 3.0);


        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, cubeVertices);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


        glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, cubeColorsBlueFace);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndicesFaceFront);
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndicesFaceFront);

        glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, cubeFillColorsFaceBack);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndicesFaceBack);
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndicesFaceBack);

        glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, cubeFillColorsFaceLeft);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndicesFaceLeft);
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndicesFaceLeft);

        glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, cubeFillColorsFaceRight);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndicesFaceRight);
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndicesFaceRight);

        glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, cubeFillColorsFaceTop);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndicesFaceTop);
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndicesFaceTop);

        glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, cubeFillColorsFaceBottom);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndicesFaceBottom);
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndicesFaceBottom);

        glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
        [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```